# Npm not saving to package.json after installation

Tags: reactjs, npm

Each time I run npm i  it does not save to package.json after successful installation rather it will save to package-lock.json file.
Please I need help. I have tried using npm cache clean --force but always get this error
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use `--save` flag. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-install#save

Comment: I tried it and it worked. But can actually use the installed npm e.g react-bootstrap, I can't actually use any of the components from react-bootstrap even after importing it. Please need urgent help.

Comment: Do you mean that you installed react-bootstrap but `import { ... } from 'react-bootstrap'` didn't work?

Comment: exactly @Julian Liu

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking `npm install`, it is executing to install all packages depends on your package.json and package-log.json.

If you have both package.json and package-lock.json, it will only check and install/update the packages and related version mentioned the 2 files. It won't modify the 2 files because package-lock.json file exists.

It package-lock.json file not exists, then it will install/update latest version from package.json, update the version installed to package.json, and create package-lock.json.

If you are asking `npm install [a package]`, then after installed it should update package.json and package-lock.json to add the new package in the file.